Is there a way to convert mjs files to js?
Is there a way to convert .mjs files to .js? Not all hosts support mjs files yet, so I'd like to convert mjs files to js files.
Background: Mozilla's PDFjs updated their code to use JavaScript modules (mjs), however I'm wrapping PDFjs in a WordPress plugin, which means anyone can install it, but most hosts don't support mjs files yet. Asking thousands of users to update their hosting to support .mjs files isn't a great option either.

How many files need to be converted?

Are you just looking to change the file extension, no syntax? If so, yes, that's incredibly simple to do.

"Not all hosts support mjs files yet" ... it's just a static asset. You know, the kind of thing that webservers serve, supported by all browsers. Even in node.js for quite awhile now. I admit I've never used WordPress, but I find that difficult to believe? Especially since WordPress is popular enough that somebody would have complained by now, and googling "mjs files wordpress" gets you this question and your github issue you filed about it on pdfjs. What is the exact problem you are having? Error messages, minimal repro case, etc?

Where and how have you actually encountered a problem?

The problem is if you try to server up a .mjs file on a server that hasn't added support for .mjs, it won't run the file.

Loading module from “https://site.local/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/pdfjs/build/pdf.mjs” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/octet-stream”).


...that would have been valuable information to include in the original question. Ok, now we're in business. You will need to change the file extension to .js, set "type": "module" in the package.json, and add type="module" to the script tags that load the js files.

It's still unclear what you mean with "a way to convert .mjs files to .js". You can rename them. That should be simple. Do you have to change the file content? If you want to change the MIME type, it depends on the server.

MDN suggests there is no need to convert, but to simply use the .js file extension as opposed to the .mjs file extension. This will still use the correct mime type and allow the functionality to remain. The trade-off is that it bucks conventions in exchange for larger compatibility.
From "JavaScript modules"MDN
:

Aside — .mjs versus .jsMDN
However, we decided to keep using .js, at least for the moment. To get modules to work correctly in a browser, you need to make sure that your server is serving them with a Content-Type header that contains a JavaScript MIME type such as text/javascript. If you don't, you'll get a strict MIME type checking error along the lines of "The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type" and the browser won't run your JavaScript. Most servers already set the correct type for .js files, but not yet for .mjs files. Servers that already serve .mjs files correctly include GitHub Pages and http-server for Node.js.


Yes, this is the issue.  "Most servers already set the correct type for .js files, but not yet for .mjs files" and asking everyone to add support for mjs to their servers is a pain because many of them have no idea how to do it.
I doubt changing mjs to js will work as I'm sure I tried that, but I can try again.

Wait.... renaming them may work. I swear I tried that and got errors before. Now I have to dig into this more. Thanks
